# loading elements with <object> tag in HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit, object-tag

I am loading a webpage which has lots of flash/gif elements embedded within *object* tags. I can see those elements in my browser, but I cannot reach them in HtmlUnit.

```
page.getByXPath("//object"); //gives empty result
```

waitForBackgroundJavaScript() doesn't help either.

Anyone had the same problem before? Thanks!!

Comment: Are those elements added to the DOM by JS or are they returned in the RAW HTML of the HTTP response?

Comment: @MostyMostacho thanks for replying. It's loaded by JS, but waiting for JS didn't help. Any insights?

Comment: I've added an explanation on how to wait for JS in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843521). Maybe it helps. Anyway, if you have issues in the JS code itself (eg: getting javascript exceptions) then this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315330) might help.